# How to get domain name from my subject line using regex?

Tags: regex

When new users sign up for our software, I get emails like:

```
Store Leads Account Created (ammar@123.com)
```

I'm trying to isolate the domain name.

I found this regex expression which worked:

```
.*@(\S+)
```

but I get left with a trailing `)`, so I get:

```
123.com)
```

How do I remove the trailing `)`, at the end?

Answer (score -1):

You may use:

```
(?<=@)[^\s)]+
```

This matches:

- `(?<=@)` assert that `@` precedes
- `[^\s)]+` then match all following non whitespace characters which are also not `)`

### Demo

Answer (score -1):

Simply put a word boundary at the end:

```
.*@(\S+)\b
```

**See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/hZIXqh/1)**.

**EXPLANATION**

```
 - .* - matches 0+ any character (except for line terminators)
 - @ - matches the character @ with index 6410 (4016 or 1008) literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group (\S+)
 - \S+ - matches any 1+ non-whitespace character (equivalent to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
 - \b - assert position at a word boundary
```